# Why is unix.stackexchange.com not optimized for mobile devices?

Tags: discussion, design, mobile

I cannot really use this site on my Nexus 6P, but it would be great to quickly look up things away from a desktop device (e.g. in a very small server room or on the subway).

Comment: Also, you need to have 5 reputation to post on meta. So I cannot ask my meta question because I could be a bot. Which I am not.

Comment: I've flagged the post for migration to the Meta site; is it just U&L that you have a problem with, or all of Stack Exchange?

Comment: It's just U&L. gaming.stackexchange.com 's mobile version works fine. Thanks for flagging!

Comment: Could you add a little more detail on what doesn’t work? I use the mobile site (not the app) quite a lot, it works fine for me (on a Nexus 5 running Android N).

Answer (score 7):

This is what it looks like on my device:

[image: Screenshot of U&L on my phone]

Versus Gaming:

[image: Screenshot of Gaming on my phone]

Are you sure you don't have your browser set to request the desktop version of the site?